# Lua 5.4, having trouble requiring a Lua module DLL (Windows)

Tags: c, visual-studio, lua, lua-api

I want to experience with the Lua internals a little bit and affiliate myself with them. I figured digging into the C API would give me some neat knowledge. I wrote up a very small module (parser.dll) in pure C:

```c
#include "parser.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "lua5.4.4.lib")

#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"

int luaL_parse(lua_State* L) {
    const char* path = lua_tostring(L, 1);
    const char* cwd = lua_tostring(L, 2);

    lua_getglobal(L, "print");
    lua_pushstring(L, "Did this run?");
    lua_callk(L, 1, 0, 0, NULL);

    return 0;
}

static const struct luaL_Reg exports[] = {
    {"parse", luaL_parse},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

LUAMOD_API int luaopen_parser(lua_State* L) {
    luaL_newlib(L, exports);
    return 1;
}
```

Parser.h:

```c
#pragma once

#ifndef lua_h
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#endif

int luaL_parse(lua_State* L);
```

And it compiles successfully. Whenever I try to require it (via `require("parser")`), I read this:

```
lua54.exe: error loading module 'parser' from file 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Lua\parser.dll':
        The specified module could not be found.
```

I feel like there's more of a mishap in my vs19 project configuration but I don't believe I can dump a text file of that configuration here. If you've any tips, please let me know! I'm not sure how to traverse the problem anymore, I've been attempting to hack at it for a little while.

One detail that may be important is that I'm building with the Lua 5.4.4 source code. As in, I downloaded the source, and just added it as an additional include directory.

On the Lua side, I don't get different results with `package.loadlib` either. That gives me nil even with funcname @ "*".

Update, I went through a dependency walker (https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) and when I click on the Lua.5.4.4.dll dependency, it says it couldn't be found on the disk. Could the lib file perhaps be messed up? I'm not sure because the program compiles fine still, no unresolved symbols.

Comment: You have created module `parser` (because of the name `luaopen_parser`) but trying to require module `ini_parser`.

Comment: That's because I copypasted a different line from the command prompt. I'll edit it because it's misleading, but that's not the issue. The dll seems like it gets recognized then fails to load. The lua file and the dll are in the same path/folder; using absolute paths gives no dice either.

Comment: I said screw it with VS19 and used GCC, and it worked instantly. So, it's a VS19 configuration problem, still unsure what.